# 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke error on face recognition test using emgu

Tags: c#, invoke, emgucv

I'm hitting a bit of a brick wall I may just lack some fundamental understanding about how to setup projects in .net (c# express 2010) but I just can not seem to get this program to work

Basically I'm trying to just setup a simple program that will take a web cam feed and check it for a face and if so fire off an even ( I'll get more complex as time goes on)

I've seen several examples of face recognition using EMGU (none that work) so i think I'm barking up the right tree but when I to the code

```
var cap = new Capture(0);
```

I get a 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke

So Ive added the appropriate (at least i think) reference dll's and added the using statements I just don't know what else to do.

Clearly I'm missing something.

I'm not sure what the best way to share my entire project is (I'm open to suggestions) but does anyone know of a working example that compiles in c# express 2010? or have a tutorial that includes what files to add?

Thanks

Comment: Please be more specific about the problem you're having. What do you mean when you say "I get a `Emgu.CV.CvInvoke"? Is this a compile-time error (in other words, you can't compile the project) or a runtime error? If it's runtime, is this an exception or something else.

Comment: Also, please specify the type of project this is (ASP.NET web application, WinForms desktop application, WPF desktop application etc.)

Comment: I get both debug and runtime error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow EmguCV wiki you should find no problem in running your code:

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation

It seems that you have not copied opencv dll's inside your bin folder

[UPDATE]
Can you try to debug this simple code and tell me what's your result?

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.UI;
using System.Drawing;

...

using (Image<Bgr, Byte> img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(400, 200, new Bgr(255, 0, 0))) 
{
   MCvFont f = new MCvFont(CvEnum.FONT.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1.0, 1.0);

   img.Draw("Hello, Stack Overflow", ref f, new Point(10, 80), new Bgr(0, 255, 0)); 

   //Show the image using ImageViewer from Emgu.CV.UI
   ImageViewer viewer = new ImageViewer(img, "Stack Test");
   viewer.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: I'll give that a try tonight and mark this as the answer if it works. I'm a little unclear that i thought that adding them as references with the correct path would have been sufficient.

Comment: Added the approate dll's (i think) but now rather than give me an error when i execute the command var cap = new Capture(0); the debuger goes into the code and then I can progress any futher) the program doesn't hang but I can't exit or see the code that its trying to execute

Comment: Would it be possible to get a working project file in c# the example i have from the site does not compile in c# express

Comment: Another thing you should check is that you have referenced the right dll's for your architecture. To be safer open your project properties and change the "Platform Target" under the "Build" tab from "Any CPU" to "X86" if you have referenced x86 dll's.

Comment: I saw that and yes im doing an x86 build. I have the following dll's included in the project do i need to add them all as refrences as well? opencv_video220.dll,opencv_core220.dll,opencv_imgproc220.dll,opencv_gpu220.dll,opencv_objdetect220.dll,opencv_features2d220.dll,opencv_flann220.dll,opencv_contrib220.dll,opencv_highgui220.dll,opencv_ml220.dll,opencv_ffmpeg220.dll,opencv_calib3d220.dll,opencv_legacy220.dll

Comment: to put it simpler take the dll's that you have mentioned (they are the correct ones) and manually copy it inside bin folder.

Comment: all the above listed dll's are in the bin/debug folder and no change.

Comment: I can step through the code till I get to images.cs and the sub AllocateData and then it just goes off into the ether and doesn't report any debugging activity

Comment: Ok but are you able to run it without debugging? Do you see the Test Window with Hello Stack Overflow text?

Comment: in non debug mode I get "See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.


System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'opencv_core220': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvRedirectError(CvErrorCallback errorHandler, IntPtr userdata, IntPtr prevUserdata)
   at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke..cctor()

Comment: If you have copied all the dll's as you told me previously it seems you have not installed MSVCRT 9.0 SP1!!! http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=A5C84275-3B97-4AB7-A40D-3802B2AF5FC2&displaylang=en

Comment: I for some reason am not able to edit the above comment. but i do have msvcrt 9.0sp1 installed  and i reinstalled it again just to make sure. still nothing. the above link is to the project i am working in to see if you can see something im missing or not. since there is 3 hours left ill just give you the bounty for all the great work thus far.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty. I have downloaded your project... As i told you in my first reply you had not copied the dll to BIN folder!!!! You have added dll's to project but then you have forgot to copy them to output folder. So to run your project you have to open it, click on cvextern.dll and on the properties window, set the CopyToOutputDirectory value to "Copy if Newer". You have to repeat this for all the dlls included in the project. You also have to modify the code i wrote above because you are using a windows form project. i edit the code above immediately...

Answer (score 0):

After a double check of your dll's it seems that you have not copied cvextern.dll !!!

Comment: I will give this a try when i get home

Comment: nevermind i found it its now targeted at 3.5 and still i dont get the code you gave me to execute

Comment: As i told in previous comment, if you have copied all the dll's as you told me and checked target frameowork, it seems you have not installed MSVCRT 9.0 SP1!!!       http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=A5C84275-3B97-4AB7-A40D-3802B2AF5FC2&displaylang=en

Comment: @Luca: Please do not post multiple answers to a question. Either edit your original answer or post your answer as a comment (which appears to be more appropriate in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Add the cvextern.dll,  and another dlls that you need copied to the output folder, as an link to dll, then go to the properties of that link, and on the advance properties, set the CopyToOutputDirectory value to "Copy if Newer", or "Copy Always". 
To add as an link, when you add an existing item, on the add Button is an arrow pointing down in the reight, click it and the "add as an link" option appears.

Comment: they were set to not copy I changed them all to always copy and still no dice

Comment: strange, it should have added an copy of the dll to your debug/release folder.